# .com extension adds random characters/numbers

Tags: url, markdown, github-pages

I'm using a domain name with this general structure: `http://mydomainname.com/`

However, when I click it, I get a 404 message saying:

[image]

And when I look in the URL, it's not `http://mydomainname.com/` but surprisingly  `http://mydomainname.com/YkPWZ/`.

How did `YkPWZ/` appear automatically and what can I do to eliminate this issue?  Sometimes accessing `http://mydomainname.com/` works fine, but most of the time the browser automatically tacks on some random characters at the end of the URL, throwing the 404 message.  This is not a browser-specific issue and I've had a few colleagues replicate this issue on different operating systems (both desktop and iOS).

P.S.  If it matters at all, I generated my website using Github Pages (markdown files, not HTML).

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to answer. What's the domain?

Comment: The domain is: `http://hyperseq.com/`.  Sometimes, when I click that link, it pops up the 404 message, and shows `http://hyperseq.com/PmlkZ/`

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with GitHub Pages. Your domain appears to be hosted somewhere else (possibly a GoDaddy Windows server: the IP address is in the GoDaddy range, and I'm seeing an ASP.NET response header). That site basically just contains an `<iframe>` that points to your GitHub Pages site. The redirects and trailing characters are happening on the GoDaddy / ASP.NET side of things, not GitHub Pages. Can you share more information about how your site is hosted?

Comment: Yes, it's hosted on GoDaddy.  The original URL is `https://hyperseq.github.io/` and I've set it up to forward with masking to `http://hyperseq.com/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite certain this is an issue on the GoDaddy side of things, though I'm unable to find any official documentation on the subject. As noted in comments above, the redirect isn't coming from GitHub Pages.

I found [an old thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/8JorwELpQW0) discussing the issue. Here is a brief summary:

- GoDaddy may use redirects like this to handle load balancing on their shared hosting servers.
- In several cases, users contacted GoDaddy to ask about the problem and

  - had the issue resolved, but
  - were never told the technical specifics of what was happening.

If you wish to stay with GoDaddy I recommend contacting them and sending them to the link I found above. They may be able to resolve the issue for you, though I wouldn't expect an explanation.

Alternatively, you can use another web host. In many circles, GoDaddy [isn't](http://www.whoishostingthis.com/hosting-reviews/go-daddy/) [rated](https://webhostinggeeks.com/providers/godaddy) [very](https://www.consumeraffairs.com/internet/godaddy.html) [highly](https://ca.hostadvice.com/hosting-company/godaddy-reviews/). It's lucky that there are so many web hosts to choose from. Alternatively, you can [use a custom domain directly with GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/), bypassing a third-party host entirely.